# How can I animate my View Controller's background to fade among multiple colors?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

How can I do that without causing infinite memory issues? I'm trying something like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        fadeBackground()
    }

    let colors = [UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.purpleColor()]
    func fadeBackground(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(4, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.colors.count)))
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[randomIndex]
        }) { (stuff Bool) -> Void in
            self.fadeBackground()
        }
    }
```

I'm afraid this will eventually eat up the memory.  How can I do this without recursion? Do I need  `[unowned self]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's the right code. Try setting `view.backgroundColor` to an initial color like `UIColor.whiteColor()` and try again. Then you can randomly pick another color with `arc4random()` or something and call the same method.

Comment: thanks I was able to get it to work.  How can I do this without recursion?

Comment: Use a NSTimer to repeatedly call a selector that has the change color code in it.` -scheduledTimerWIth.....` that calls every 4 seconds (for you)

Comment: Thanks! I do have one more question...do you know why my button action stopped working? I have one button dragged on it using storyboard. If I don't run the animation, the button event works, but when I run it, the button doesn't respond.

Comment: Use UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction as an option parameter in method animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: